# Default URI Replace

Tags: xml, apache-camel, marklogic, marklogic-8, mlcp

I am picking up a file from a folder specified using Camel File Component and mlcp automatically injects the filename to the default URI and i dont want the filename

When i put the file in `D:/Camel` with file named `test_1.xml` mlcp produces a URI

> /D:/Camel/test_1.xml

. I want `/D:/Camel/test_1.xml` to be replaced with '/Vikram' and i want to inject a header from camel to MLCP component too making the final URI be

> /Vikram/1

where `1` will be the header value of `myHeader`

```
 from("file://D:/Camel")
    .routeId("File_Pickup_Route")
    .setHeader("myHeader")
    .to("mlcp:localhost:8000?username=admin&password=admin&output_collections=test
      + "&database=testdb"
      + "&output_uri_replace=/D:/Camel,"
      + "'/Vikram'");
```

I referred the link

> https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/export#id_67189

Any way to achieve what i want ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to put the strings into double quotes:

`-output_uri_replace "/uriToReplace,'final-uri'"`

Therefore (without knowing much about the syntax of camel):

```
from("file://D:/Camel")
    .routeId("File_Pickup_Route")
    .setHeader("myHeader")
    .to("mlcp:localhost:8000?username=admin&password=admin&output_collections=test
      + "&database=testdb"
      + "&output_uri_replace="/D:/Camel,'/Vikram'");
```

(I have changed the last line).

Give this a go and let me know if it worked or not.

For more information please read: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/import#id_42798

Comment: Hi Tamas thanks for the answer. The problem is am able to replace the folderpath but not the filename as i described in my question. you are just replacing the folder path. I want /D:/Camel/test_1.xml to be replaced with '/Vikram' but the output am getting is '/Vikram/test_1.xml' from what you suggested

Comment: &output_uri_replace="/D:/Camel/${file:name},'/Vikram'"); but am not able resolve $ symbol. i dont know how to replace filenames inside mlcp if anything is available... Thanks in advance